# Hide page extension also call file instead of folder if same folder exist

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Right now i hide page extension using .htaccess file. But i am getting problem when same folder name exist.
Like i have a page which name is about.html so in url it called as http://sitename.com/about

But also there is a folder which name is about. So in that case browser show folder not about.html.

Any one pls help me to sort out this issue.

I am using this code in .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find solution. Now i am using this code

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d

RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ index.html [NC,L]

Answer (score 0):

you need to turn of the directory slash off to rewrite your file :

```
DirectorySlash off
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Turning the directory slash off will allow you to access
The directory /about/ with a trailing slash. and
/about without a trailing slash will be rewritten to /about.html

Comment: It not working. pls check here
http://careforadog.com/about  . It should be call http://careforadog.com/about.html